# Так как же всё-таки настроить чистые URL для drupal?

Tags: nginx, drupal

Требуется настроить чистые URL для использования Drupal 8 на сервере nginx. Я находил множество вариантов конфигурационных файлов. Все они выглядят по-разному, и я пробовал использовать разные варианты, но все они работали не так, как мне надо.

Сейчас мой конфиг выглядит так:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

server_name _;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

location ~ \.php(/|$) {

#   try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
}
# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}
}
```

Так вот, если обратиться к разделу, например, администрирования по адресу вида `index.php/admin`, то всё работает успешно. Однако если обратиться по адресу `/admin`, то выводится ошибка `No input file specified`.

Как должна выглядеть конфигурация для того, чтобы URL правильно распознался в обоих случаях?

Answer (score 1):

```
server {

  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/example;
  index index.php;

  error_log /var/www/log/example_error.log;

  location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
  }

  # Block access to hidden directories
  location ~ (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
  }

  location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
    return 403;
  }

  # No php is touched for static content
  location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # The address or socket on which FastCGI requests are accepted. Set yours in www.conf
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  # Clean URLs
  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ /index.php;
  }

  # Image styles
  location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

}
```

Comment: Мне не хочется переписывать весь конфиг заново, тем более на моём локальном хосте стоят и сайты на других движках. Других вариантов нет?